# How do I determine how long I can keep my solenoid powered, for safety sake and before ordering it?

Tags: solenoid

I got a solenoid recently, a [DSOS-0416-24D](http://www.deltaww.com/filecenter/Products/download/04/0409/DSOS-0416-D.pdf) from [DigiKey](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/delta-electronics/DSOS-0416-24D/1144-1401-ND/6599949), but it gets pretty hot after only 2 seconds of engaging it.  How can I know ahead of time what kind of heat a solenoid can withstand, and how long it can stay engaged safely at it's specified voltage?

For a run-of-the-mill "24V solenoid" like this, I can't assume to be able to plug it in and leave it on all the time, right?  Is it limited only to 50% duty cycle and 1.5sec (assumedly through PWM) like it says in the document above?

In reality am I expected to do my own safety tests to find out what is safe for my application and how many seconds it can be on for without catching fire?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the data sheet states a duty cycle or maximum "On" time, as in the one you linked, then you can assume that if you exceed that specification to device will overheat and may be damaged.

If the data sheet says "continuous duty" or words to that effect, then you should be able to power it with its rated voltage indefinitely.

As with anything, if you violate a thing's ratings, it will probably be damaaged.

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet is telling you that it will overheat if turned on for > 1.5 s - although this will be after it has got to working temperate. It will then need to cool down before powering it again. The average power it can tolerate is 3.8 W (from memory) × 0.5.

What the datasheet isn't telling you is the temperature rise in °C/W. You have to decide whether to trust the datasheet, do some experimental measurements or create it by some safety factor.